# Failed server and advanced startup options menu.

Tags: windows-server-2003

Lets say you perform daily backups.

Suddenly, one server fails and you cannot boot the operating system. You can get to the advanced startup options menu. Describe the steps you should take to try to diagnose the problem. Then, assume that none of these steps work and you must restore the computer from backup. Please describe the exact steps you must take to restore the system.

I'm in the 9th grade and i am doing a paper that is about job situations in my possible future and i chose computers. I know nothing about computers but i am intersested in it and i would like to wow my teacher if someone could help me. Thanks in advance -Brad

Comment: We are not going to do your homework for you. Tell is what you have done already and what areas you are having trouble with and we will gladly help, but don't ask us to do your work for you, unless your going to come and do my job for me???

Comment: Sorry and i wouldint know where to start to do your job... I am researching and not finding answers.

Comment: @Brad Please give the [faq] a read. It would probably "wow" your teacher more if you could perform some research on your own.

Answer (score 2):

> You can get to the advanced startup options menu.

Boot to the last known good configuration, or to safe mode with or without networking.

> Then, assume that none of these steps work and you must restore the computer from backup.
>   Please describe the exact steps you must take to restore the system.

What backup system do you have? Tape? Disk? Full system backup? Data only? Bare-metal recovery support? Is it a physical or virtual server?

What I would do is open the virtual backup console, click "restore", choose which server and which storage space to restore to, and then click run.

In the case of a physical server, insert the baremetal recovery image and the backup media, boot it. Follow the instructions.

Or, reinstall the OS and backup software, use the backup software to restore from the backup.

**Edit**

If you really want to wow your teacher, download the 120 day trial virtual machine of Server 2003 from Microsoft here ( http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19727 ) and run it in Virtual PC, and get it backed up, and then restored. (Wont be a world of fun, though).

Comment: Hey thanks they are giving me a hard time on here!

Comment: I have found several websites that are telling me almost the same thing.I'm just trying to learn this stuff thanks again -Brad

Comment: @Brad - He really *did* answer your question, from a lot of different stand points as well. Start from the top, anything you don't understand, look up research and understand it till it's not giberish any more. That's how we all started(ish).